# Detect right when page view controller is paging (iOS)

Tags: uipageviewcontroller

I implemented a pageViewController, with the `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` and `UIPageViewControllerDataSource`.

I am successfully able to get when the page has swiped and finished animating using `willTransitionTo` and `didFinishAnimating` delegate methods, respectively, however I need to know when the page is beginning to transition to the next page, not when its completed (I want to update some UI).

I tried pageViewController delegate methods `willTransitionTo` (fired when swiping begins), `didFinishAnimating` (when swiping ends), as well as the datasource methods `viewControllerBefore`, `viewControllerAfter`, `presentationCount`, and `presentationIndex` but I am still not getting the timing I am looking for.

How do I detect right when the page view controller BEGINS transitioning to another page?  Not when the page view controller began swiping, or ended transitioning.